# Patching commands does not work for /RenewDocumentCommands

Tags: sectioning, moderncv, patching, xpatch

I am using the `moderncv` class provided by TeXLive 2016 and in it the `\section` command is redefined as follows:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak
```

I want to modify the vertical spacing in the first line, that is **2.5ex** to be explicit. If I try to do it with macros from the `xpatch` package it fails due to unknown reasons.

```
\xpatchcmd{\section}{2.5ex}{15ex}{\typeout{----Section command patched----}}{\typeout{----Section command cannot be patched----}}
```

Why is this the case? If I enclose the `\RenewDocumentCommand` between `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` commands and modify the length **2.5ex** to suit my needs everything works fine. Is it a limitation of `xpatch` commands? I am really curious about this behaviour and want to know why I experience this.

**EDIT** A MWE is provided below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\usepackage{amsfonts,color}
%\usepackage{graphicx,calc}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
\setlength{\footskip}{36pt}

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name

\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{#2}{\bfseries #2}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{2.5ex}{15ex}{\typeout{----Section command patched----}}{\typeout{----Section command cannot be patched----}}
%\xpatchcmd{\section}{\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}{\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{1.95ex}}{\typeout{----Section command patched----}}{\typeout{----Section command cannot be patched----}}

%%% If you UNCOMMMENT this everything works 
%\makeatletter
%\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
%  \par\addvspace{5.5ex}%originally 2.5ex
%  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
%  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
%  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
%  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
%  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
%  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
%\makeatother

%%%%
\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle % Print the CV title
    \section*{Education}

    \section*{Technical Skills}

    \section*{Experience}

    \section*{Certificates and Achievements}

    \section*{Projects}

    \section*{Schools and Workshops}

    \section*{Languages}

    \section*{Associations}

    \section*{Interests}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not just fragments. Do you have enclosed the `\xpatchcmd` trial  with `\makeatletter...\makeatother` as well?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added a code reproducing the issue.

Comment: I forgot: `xpatch` can't be used for macros that have been defined with `xparse` in general. See the section 5 of the `xpatch` documentation

Comment: This is by design. The document-level macros created using `xparse` are not intended to be patchable. Typically, these should only be wrappers for lower level functions. Those functions can be redefined etc. The wrappers can be `\Renew`ed `\Declare`d etc., but they cannot be patched and ought not be.

Comment: @cfr I understood and got my answer to my original question. What is the advantage of using `xparse` is it to conform with `LaTeX 3`?

Comment: It provides powerful tools for parsing user input. Much more flexible than the 2e commands and much safer and easier to use than the lower level TeX macros. It is recommended that all document-level macros based on `expl3` use the `xparse` wrappers. (Probably there are other reasons I don't know about, also.)

Comment: `xpatch` only acts on commands defined with`\def`, `\newcommand` (and variants thereof) or `\DeclareRobusCommand`. There are no plans to support the `xparse` defined commands.

Comment: To be more precise: `\newcommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand` inner workings are decades old and aren't bound to change. Within LaTeX3, basing code to inner details is the wrong thing to do, because internals (macros with `__` in their names) are not guaranteed to be the same forever.

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning there was `patchcmd`, by Michael Downes, which allowed to add tokens at the beginning or end of macros defined with `\newcommand` or `\DeclareRobustCommand` (but without optional arguments).

Then `etoolbox` allowed much more freedom, however only doing its work on macros defined with `\newcommand` or `\newrobustcmd`, but without optional argument.

An increasing demand for patching led to the release of `xpatch`, which is able to “guess” whether a command is defined with `\newcommand`, `\newrobustcmd` or `\DeclareRobustCommand`, with or without a leading optional argument.

While `xpatch` itself is written using `expl3`, there is no plan to extend it in order to allow patching commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` (from `xparse`).

One reason is that `\newcommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand` are decades old and they're essentially unchangeable, because several packages depend on their actual implementation. Some words about how `xpatch` can help in understanding the matter.

Suppose we want to patch the macro `\foo`, defined with `\newcommand\foo[2]{...}`. No problem,

```
\xpatchcmd\foo{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

directly uses

```
\patchcmd\foo{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

where `\patchcmd` is the main macro defined in `etoolbox`. If `\foo` is defined with `\newcommand{\foo}[2][default]{...}` (with an optional argument), the above call of `\xpatchcmd` actually does

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\foo\endcsname{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

which becomes

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\foo\space\endcsname{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

in case `\foo` has been defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[2][default]{...}`.

The purpose of `xpatch` is to relieve the user from having to guess what complicated combination of commands to use. It is apparent that `xpatch` can only work if the indirect definitions done when optional arguments are involved don't change.

On the other hand, the `expl3` approach is completely different.

The idea is that there will be an intermediate level between `expl3` and the user interface, so in the future `\NewDocumentCommand` will use this intermediate level and patching should become useless. But there is also another reason: in the LaTeX3 approach, only *public* interfaces should be relied upon, whereas private ones aren't available.

The implementation of `\NewDocumentCommand` relies on several private functions and indeed, these have recently changed. Supporting `\NewDocumentCommand` defined macros is, in principle, feasible: if we do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{O{default}m}{...}
```

then `\show\foo` displays

```
> \foo=\protected macro:
->\__xparse_start:nNNnnn {O{default}m}\foo  \foo code {\__xparse_grab_D:w []\__
xparse_grab_m_1:w }{{\prg_do_nothing: default}\c_novalue_tl }{}.
```

and the actual macro to patch would be `\foo code` (with a space in the name). But this is internal and not cast into stone.